# Check if option is selected jQuery (in the current page)

Tags: javascript, jquery, conditional-statements, selected

I know how check if the option is selected and the following condition works but I have to refresh the page to applicate the changes.

Here is my code:

```
$(function (){
        var select = $("div.form-group:nth-of-type(2)");

        if ($("#id_issue_type option:selected").val() === "other"){
            select.show();
        }

        else {
            select.hide();
        }

    });
```

The problem is I have to refresh the page and I'd like to applicate the changes directly after I selected the option. My purpose being to hide and show a field depending of the value selected.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Use `onchange` event of select

Comment: when page is refreshed control is set to its default value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could use change event for drop down, like this:

```js
$( ".target" ).change(function() {
  alert( "Handler for .change() called." );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <select class="target">
    <option value="option1" selected="selected">Option 1</option>
    <option value="option2">Option 2</option>
  </select>
</form>
```